# MySql Start failed with : 'The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/iZ23uaxhiftZ.pid).'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am installing MySql Server in my Ubuntu. Steps are as the following:

1. Firt, I download the Linux Gerneric version of mysql: mysql-5.6.27-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz
2. I untar the downloaded package and copy all the contents to /usr/local/mysql: cp -r mysql-5.6.27-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64 /usr/local/mysql
3. I add group and user: 'groupadd mysql' and 'useradd -r -g mysql mysql'
4. Then I get into /usr/local/mysql folder, and use: 'chown -R mysql:mysql ./' to make mysql be the owner of the current folder.
5. Use './scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql' for installing MySql database. Then I added owner using 'chown -R root:root ./' and 'chown -R mysql:mysql data
6. I try to start MySql using 'support-files/mysql.server start', it tried to start the db but failed with error: 
   [image]
   I could not find any .pid file in data folder:

[image]

but just a 'iZ23uaxhiftZ.err' file:

[image]

I have tried some solutions provided on the Internet, but get no luck, so how can I solve this? Thank!